# how to hide the path in a hyperlink parsed to an xlsx file

Tags: r, excel, hyperlink

I am trying to link files to a xlsx file. I have xlsx file named my file.xlsx
I have a myfolder and 3 files are in that folder names file1.pdf file2.pdf and file3.pd

in my xlsx file in Sheet1, I have a column with header named File and 3 names file1, file2 and file3 .

```
xlsx_file <- '/Users/admin/Desktop/myfolder/myfile.xlsx'
```

I go to specific sheet

```
myxlsx <- read.xlsx(xlsx_file, sheet = 'Sheet1')
filePaths <- c("file1", "file2", "file3")
```

Then I make the link between the folder and each cell of the xlsx

```
myfiles <- sprintf("/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/%s.pdf", filePaths)
```

I make it hyperlink

```
class(myfiles) <- 'hyperlink'
```

I load it as wb

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file = xlsx_file)
```

I write to it in sheet1, based on myfiles and starting from second row

```
writeData(wb,"Sheet1",x = myfiles,startRow = 2)
```

then save it

```
saveWorkbook(wb, xlsx_file, overwrite = TRUE)
```

so far so good, the problem is that it will show the path to the file in the xlsx.
how can I hide it?
I dont want the hyperlink to show

```
/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file1.pdf
/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file2.pdf
/User/admin/Desktop/myfolder/file3.pdf
```

instead I want to show the hyperlink to be

```
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
file3.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of excel it will be a different dialog, but should still be the same methodology. Keep "Use relative path for hyperlink" active and dont specify a folder in the Path: filename.pdf
[image]